# SOP for using default measures in MDX and SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I'm going through one of the few highly-rated books on MDX, *Practical MDX Queries* and the book makes heavy use of the fact you can use default measures in MDX.  Personally, I don't like this feature and I think whatever amount of keystrokes it saves ultimately isn't worth it.  What's the harm in explicitly stating what you're looking from?

```
select
from
[cube name]
```

just seems like you're inviting trouble, and it gets worse when you throw something into the slicer.  Any other opinions on this?

Answer (score 1):

In some cases you want your MDX query to take into account the changes you made in the cube configuration without rewriting it.

You can still add `[dim].[hierarchy].DefaultMember` in your slicer but it is useless and makes the query less readable.

Comment: I'm curious how, in your opinion, does adding the measure which you are slicing add ambiguity?  Granted, I'm a noob at this, but it seems to make that being as explicit as possible is a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, relying on the default measure is usually bad luck. It's better to be explicit and avoid surprises later.

Comment: That's what I would think, but I've never worked in a professional programming environment.